# Issue with NSURLSession with multiple downloads in background with multiple sessions and multiple segments

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, multipart, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

We have crated session with below configuration code. I call this method for each task I crate.

```
+(NSURLSession ) getNewSessionWithID:(NSString )sessionID delegateObject:(id)sender 
{
    NSURLSession *session;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:sessionID];
    NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount=10;
    queue.name=sessionID;

    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:sender delegateQueue:queue];

    NSLog(@"Session ID :%@",session);
    NSLog(@"QUEUE : %@",queue);
   return session;
}
```

Even multiple sessions are created for multiple tasks only one session is active and only one task is executing and for that task only three part are downloading for that one session.

This method is called to create and start download task.

```
-(void)DLRequestAllRenge:(NSMutableArray*)arrayrange andFileinfo:(FileInfo *)fileInfoObj
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayAllParts=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    fileInfoObj.tempPath=[fileInfoObj UniqueFileName:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:[fileInfoObj.Name stringByDeletingPathExtension]]];
    [self createTempDirectory:fileInfoObj.tempPath];
    NSLog(@"REQ Session:%@",fileInfoObj.session);
    for (int i=0; i<arrayrange.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *rangString = [arrayrange objectAtIndex:i];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileInfoObj.URL]];
        [request setValue:rangString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];

        NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%d).data",[fileInfoObj.Name stringByDeletingPathExtension],i];
        NSString *filePath=[fileInfoObj.tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        FileInfo *subFileInfo=[[FileInfo alloc]init];
        subFileInfo.URL=fileInfoObj.URL;
        subFileInfo.Name=fileName;
        subFileInfo.Path=filePath;
        subFileInfo.Folder=[fileInfoObj getCurrentFolderName:filePath];
        subFileInfo.Range=rangString;
        subFileInfo.isDownloaded=NO;
        subFileInfo.NSUrlSessionID=fileInfoObj.NSUrlSessionID;
        subFileInfo.Progress=@"0";
        subFileInfo.Priority=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        subFileInfo.fileDetail=@"Connecting...";
        subFileInfo.fileStatus=RequestStatusDownloading;
        subFileInfo.request=request;
        subFileInfo.startTime=[NSDate date];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [fileInfoObj.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
        downloadTask.taskDescription=filePath;
        [downloadTask resume];
        subFileInfo.DownloadTask=downloadTask;
        [arrayAllParts addObject:subFileInfo];

    }
    fileInfoObj.parts=arrayAllParts;

    [downloadingArray addObject:fileInfoObj];

    [bgDownloadTableView reloadData];

}
```

**Issue 1**
Why all sessions are not active?

**Issue 2**
Why only three part for one task and one session is downloading?

Is there any way we can activate more session for download more part concurrently?

Please help me with this. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

We are able to download data using the above code but the issue is I am not able to get any downloaded data when any downloading task is stopped using `-suspend` or `-cancel`.

Is there any way I am able to retrieve raw data not the resumeData but the original downloaded data?